# splitting a text string - variable vs. column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I run this piece

```
--
-----------
DECLARE @QCSteps varchar(max)
SET @QCSteps = '42 - step 0;#43 - step 1;#44 - step 2;#45 - step 3'

DECLARE @separator varchar(max)
SET @separator = ';#'

DECLARE @Splited table(id int IDENTITY(1,1), item varchar(max))

SET @QCSteps = REPLACE(@QCSteps, @separator, ''' UNION ALL SELECT ''')
SET @QCSteps = ' SELECT  ''' + @QCSteps + '''  ' 

INSERT INTO @Splited
EXEC(@QCSteps)

SELECT * FROM @Splited
```

and it produces this

```
----
---------------
[text string nicely split in 4][1]
```

How do I run this reading text strings from an existing table column?

Answer (score 1):

You can't using this approach.

You would need to `CROSS APPLY` onto a table valued function and TSQL table valued functions can't execute dynamic SQL (CLR ones can but that would be silly as it is trivial to split strings in CLR anyway as here http://dataeducation.com/sqlclr-string-splitting-part-2-even-faster-even-more-scalable/).

You will need to use a different implementation of your split function. For example one from here https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 0):

This is an XML safe inline version.

You may also notice that we return the Item Sequence as well.  This is optional, but I've found many uses for it.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
  (1,'42 - step 0;#43 - step 1;#44 - step 2;#45 - step 3')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
From  @YourTable A
Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(P2.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.SomeCol,';#','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as P1
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS P2(i)
            ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  RetSeq  RetVal
1   1       42 - step 0
1   2       43 - step 1
1   3       44 - step 2
1   4       45 - step 3
```

Comment: @texastonie Never had a doubt  :)